# Solving poisson equation in polar coordinates for a separable potential.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, poissons-equation, potential-theory

I would like to get a step-by-step solution of the Poisson equation (in polar coordinates) below

$$\nabla^2\psi(r, \phi) = 2 k(r, \phi)$$

where $\psi(r, \phi)$ is seperable (i.e. $\psi(r, \phi) = f(r)g(\phi)$) and

$$k(r, \phi) = \frac{\theta_E}{2r} \left( 1 + k_m \cos(m \phi) \right)$$

with $\theta_E, k_m, m$ being constants.

The solution for $\psi(r, \phi)$ is given in this paper, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/765/2/134/pdf (Eq. 4-5, for $m\ne1$ and $m=1$, respectively). The solution given in the above paper is,

$$\psi(r, \phi) = \theta_E~ r \left( 1 - \frac{k_m}{m^2 - 1} \cos(m\phi) \right)\\m\ne1$$

and

$$\psi(r, \phi) = \theta_E~ r \left( 1 + \frac{k_m}{m^2 - 1} \ln (r) \cos\phi \right) \\m=1$$

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried solving the equation yourself? How far have you gotten? Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: it's been a while since I last solved a DE so I dont have much to show. I looked at the solution to the Laplace equation (i.e. $\nabla^2\phi = 0$) for when $\psi$ is separable. Now I trying to work out what I would get if I only assume a function form for $g(\phi) = (1 + a k_m cos(m\phi))$, although I am not sure this is the right way to proceed (I feel like I am cheating because I know the solution).